# How can I answer the question "你什么时候开始学中文的?"

Tags: grammar, mandarin, vocabulary, writing, learning

How can I answer the question "你什么时候开始学中文的?"
I cannot answer the "什么时候" questions. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: In my view, the "的" implies that the studying had already started and the question is when.

Answer (score 1):

'什么时候' = 'what time' = 'when'

You can answer with one of the following:

1. [Since the time of ]. E.g. "Started since 2016" (從 2016 年開始)
2. [from a length of time ago]. E.g. "Started from five years ago" (五年前开始)

> Q: "你什么时候开始学中文的?"

> A: "我是從2016年開始学中文的"/ "我是五年前开始学中文的" (long version)

> A: "從2016年開始"/ "五年前开始" (short version)

> A: "2016"/ "五年前" (shortest version, just state a year or a length of time ago)

More example of '什么时候' question:

Q: 你什么时候吃晚飯的?

A: 晚上七時 (a time) If the question is about what is the regular time you have dinner'

A: 三小時前 (a length of time ago) If the question is about what specific time you ate your dinner tonight

Comment: In your view is 几时 more appropriate than 时候 in the specific context of the question? As in 你几时开始学中文的?

Comment: I would say 几时 is a more colloquial form of 什么时候. e.g. 我几时叫你做笨蛋了? =  我什么时候叫你做笨蛋了?

Comment: I asked because normally it is "when", i.e. a certain date when a person starts learning a language, not "what time" as 什么时候 would mean. Unless of course the context is clear that a specific time is asked for, like what time your Chinese language classes start.

Comment: @Wayne Cheah Now you mentioned it, 几时 seems more specific  and 什么时候 is more general.  Meaning 明天 or 十二點 can be the answer to 什么时候出發; and 十二點 would be the better answer to 几时出發

Answer (score 1):

"你什么时候开始学中文的?"

When did you start learning Chinese?

"你什么时候开始学中文?"

When will you start learning Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

Answer the same as you do in your language: if someone asks about time, name a time in your answer!

> "你什么时候开始学中文的?"

Possible answers：

下周一。
Next Monday.

下年八月。
Next year in August.

在冬季。
In winter.

从来没学过。
I never studied Chinese.

我不用学啊，我就是中国人！
Don't need to study, I'm Chinese!

Comment: The question is followed by a `的`, means it is asking about a fact in the past. So the answer should not be a time in the future. Also, `下年` is technically wrong, it should be `明年` as `the next year`. `下半年` is valid, though. It means `the second half of this year`.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for telling me, I get carried away sometimes and forget to think clearly!